# Flutter - Rating and Review System With SmoothStarRating And Rest API

Tags: php, database, api, flutter

I have a SmoothStarRating widget in my flutter code I need a full rating and review system that I can apply so users can get to rate a particular product with their review and I can display the cumulative and total average rating and review of users for each product. I want this to be connected to a DB with a rest API PHP. Below is my SmoothStarRating.

```
                                      Scaffold(
                                        body:SmoothStarRating(
                                                    allowHalfRating: true,
                                                    onRatingChanged: (v) {
                                                      rating = v;
                                                      setState(() {});
                                                    },
                                                    starCount: 5,
                                                    rating: rating,
                                                    size: 20.0,
                                                    filledIconData: Icons.star,
                                                    halfFilledIconData:
                                                        Icons.star_half,
                                                    color: colorGreen,
                                                    borderColor: colorGreen,
                                                    spacing: 0.0));
```

Comment: So, what is the question? Asking people to write the whole backend for you isn't a question...

Comment: I am just looking for a lead basically to help me achieve this and will be glad if I can get one, be it an article already published.

Comment: Generally you should always start with official documentation and examples. Flutter has what you need [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#networking). As for PHP API and DB stuff, there are thousands of tutorials both in written form (which I prefer) and videos. Also I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The link sent doesn't show give an answer to my question. I was expecting you to guide me on how I can use smoothratingbar to get the value of rating and review from users and submit to database through my rest api and also how to get cummulative or total rating from users to show rating and review of each product. I have my rest api  created already I just need a guide on how to come about it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally am able to work out something for the above question in case anyone needs a solution for such. I make use of SmoothRatingBar. I add 
  smooth_star_rating: to my Pubspec.yaml and imported it in my activity. After which I initialized double rating = 0.0; Used a TextFormField to get title and reviews respectively and submit the value of the rating, TextFormField for title and review through the rest API I created to my database. Find code below:

```
import 'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart';

double rating = 0.0;

return Scaffold(
           body:Container(child:Column(children<Widget>[
                   SmoothStarRating(
                  allowHalfRating: true,
                  halfFilledIconData: Icons.star_half,
                  onRatingChanged: (v) {
                    this.rating = v;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  starCount: 5,
                  rating: rating,
                  size: 60.0,
                  filledIconData: Icons.star,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  borderColor: Colors.grey,
                  spacing: 0.0),]),

TextFormField(labelText: "Review Title (i.e Nice trip)",
                ),
TextFormField(labelText: "Your review...",
                ),

RawMaterialButton(onPressed: (){...your submission to rest API here...
                  },
                       child: Text(
                      "Send Review",
                    ),)

);
```